# AndroidStudio Library resource sharing

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

today i was encounting a problem with Android Studio.

I have this project tree:

- application (this is executable app)
- ui (this is library)
- ui-common (this is library)
- ui-tablet (this is library)
- ui-phone (this is library)

application use ui
ui use ui-tablet and ui-phone
ui-phone use ui-common
ui-tablet use ui-common

ui-common contains common java code, drawable and strings resources

now, i try compile project, but have next error:
"error: package home.test.ui.common does not exist on import home.test.ui.common.R;"

java classes are available normal, but R class did not exists... file build\source\r\debug\sta\android\ui\common generated normally

gradle's file for my projects:
-ui

```
...
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile project(":ui-common")
    compile project(":ui-phone")
    compile project(":ui-tablet") 
}
...
```

-ui-common

```
...
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
}
...
```

-ui-phone

```
...
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile project(":ui-common")
}
...
```

-ui-tablet

```
...
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile project(":ui-common")
}
...
```

-application

```
...
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(":ui")
}
...
```

in .iml files library is included too:
for ui-phone and ui-tablet project:

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="ui-common" exported="" />
```

for ui project:

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="ui-phone" exported="" />
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="ui-tablet" exported="" />
```

for application project

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="ui" exported="" />
```

how i can setup projects ui-common for sharing resource with ui-tablet and ui-phone project?

**Update 1**
ui-common\build\source\r contains only release folder, no debug folder are generated.
i try to change type of dependency from 'compile' to 'compile debug' for ui-common in ui-phone project. after this compilation of ui-phone project run normally, but i have error for other projects. why android studio / gradle not generated debug output? for other library both (debug and release generated normally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i was solve my problem. my mistake relative to package name and resource merge

in ui-phone project i must use ui-phone.R because resource already merged!